# bcrypt password - what to save to the database?

Tags: python, database, string, python-3.x, bcrypt

I learn password hashing. What should be saved to the database?
I have the snippet from one tutorial:

```
import bcrypt
hashed_passwd = bcrypt.hashpw(bytes('p@ssw0rd', 'utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
print(hashed_passwd);
#b'$2b$12$AR90MfCEY2WOAkYmzQBaVuHL49rrH2d5WR/prOMmrP6.zD0d.Dv/K'
```

Should it be saved to the database this
`"b'$2b$12$AR90MfCEY2WOAkYmzQBaVuHL49rrH2d5WR/prOMmrP6.zD0d.Dv/K'"`

or this?

`"$2b$12$AR90MfCEY2WOAkYmzQBaVuHL49rrH2d5WR/prOMmrP6.zD0d.Dv/K"`

If the second then how to remove this "b" letter from the begining?

Comment: To my knowledge the hash always begins with the dollar sign ($).

Comment: The `b'...'` isn't really there, that's just how python prints a bytes object, there is nothing to remove. How you store this in a db depends on the column type you want to save it in. If it is a text column you would need to decode it to a str first, for a binary column you would use it as it is.